# Geckofx-Core - System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, winforms, exe, xulrunner, geckofx

I Integrated Geckofx45.64 in my Windows Forms Application - On some Windows10 distributions i get the following error right after startup:

```
System.DllNotFoundException
at Gecko.Xpcom.Alloc(IntPtr)
at Gecko.nsAString..ctor()
at Gecko.nsAString..ctor(System.String)
at Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(System.String)
at Vault_Forms_App.Program.Main
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Have a customer with the same problem using GeckFfx60.64 package. Anyone know which redistributable is needed?

Comment: I figured it out: VC++ 2015 Redistributable (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution can be found https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/194/unable-to-load-dll-mozglue.

With the latest version of geckofx-45, for some reason the files msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll are missing in the Firefox folder. You can either copy them from an older version or install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio **2013**

Answer (score 2):

Try to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it did not help.